# Having issues with animations of objects that come from a prefab

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation

So let me preface this that, i am very new to unity this is my first week actually lol and i couldnt exactly find anything that would answer my question.

Anyways, i have this like thwomp object that has 3 animation states crush, reset, and wait. and it goes up and down as you would see it normally just on a timer because of the wait. it is done by adding the position property and then moving the y up and down. pretty simple i think, couldnt think of anything better. it works perfectly just like i want it too.

but when i made it a prefab and try to make more of them, the animation for the copies have the same x and y as the original. so like even though i can change the base like default positioning of them whenever the game starts and the animation plays they just perfectly overlap with the first original one that the prefab was made with. when i try to change the x coordinate on the copies animation it updates the x coordinates for all them. this happens even when i delete the prefab and just manually make copies with ctrl + d as well (im not sure if this any different?) . i assume this is because they all share the same 3 animations so when you change the animation it changes it for all them and that makes sense.

but i really dont want to make 3 seperate animations for each replica thwomp i make, i feel like there definitely has to be a better way. my original thought of how it would be was they would share the same animation, but like within the object its self the animation values like the position are exclusive to the object so they could differ inbetween each one.

ill include a link a picture to like further convey what i have going on here so its easier to understand. https://i.stack.imgur.com/baEi8.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to change the localPosition not the world position.  This thread has a little discussion about it but basically you need to use the x, y, z you get from the Animator as an offset to localPosition.

Pseudo code:
`transform.localPosition.y += animators position.y`

https://forum.unity.com/threads/playing-animation-local-to-position-in-unity.53832/#post-489101

Special note: Using an animator is pretty heavy.  For simple stuff like this I would suggest just scripting it.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for how i could do something like i have above but in script?

Comment: Well, I'm not quite sure how you are moving it but if you simply want it to go up and down continuously you could just use the PingPong method.  It's the easiest way to go I think.
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.PingPong.html
Then take the return value of `PingPong` and add it to localPosition.y